# MediaPlayer Issue?

Tags: android, piano

I'm developing a simple piano app for my own interest. The problem is that when i press a key, I have to wait until the sound is finished to play again the same key! Is there any way to play that key and not wait until the sound is finished?

```
               whitekey2 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button3);
               final MediaPlayer D4 = MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.d4);

            whitekey2.setOnTouchListener(new  OnTouchListener(){

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                 switch (event.getAction()){


                 case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

                  D4.start();                     

                 case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:


                      }
                return false;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try

```
           whitekey2 = (Button)rootView.findViewById(R.id.button3);

        whitekey2.setOnTouchListener(new  OnTouchListener(){

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

             switch (event.getAction()){


             case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

              MediaPlayer.create(getActivity(), R.raw.d4).start();                     

             case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:


                  }
            return false;
        }
```

Creating a new MediaPlayer on each press should allow you to create multiple sounds. Be careful with deallocating memory however, this could end up leaving many MediaPlayers just laying around...